# input box not fitting inside div cross browser

Tags: html, css, input, cross-browser

I am having trouble keeping my input box's inside my `div`. It looks very nice in safari and chrome but in firefox it overflows into the next line causing problems.

The code is way too long, so here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U8y2K/). Please let me know if I can better assist.

Here's what it looks like in Safari/Chrome:

[image]

And here's in Firefox:
[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a real simple fix to my question.

I edited the following and added a line-height to the div so that it would raise the text up a bit through out all browsers.

```
.sectionBlock {
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  height:18px;
  line-height:14px;
}
.formLine {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  padding:2px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:12px;
}
```

Thanks to @robjb for re-editing my question for me and to @Danko for taking a look through the code.